# "What does it mean 'something'" Vs. "What does 'something' mean?"

Tags: sentence-choice, syntax

I always said "What does it mean '-----'?". (For example: What does it mean 'legend'?).
Today I had thought maybe I'm mistaken  and it should be: "What does 'something' mean?" (i.e. What does 'legend' mean?). But I saw the first usage so many times among non-native English speakers, that I really doubt if my new thought is right or not.

Comment: Of the two, "What does 'legend' mean?" is much more idiomatic. I am a native English speaker.

Comment: The difference is that _what does something mean_ is grammatical.

Comment: As the other comments already state, "What does 'legend' mean?" is the form that is grammatically correct in standard English.

If you really want a sentence structure that has the term at the end, you can ask: "What is the meaning of 'legend'?", but that, whilst grammatically correct, can feel unnatural.

A similar (also incorrect) construct that I have seen: "What 'legend' means?", and it makes me shudder. I console myself by believing there is an ellipsis and the actual question is: "Please could someone tell me what 'legend' means?", because then it makes sense!

Comment: @Spiritman Yes, "What is the meaning of 'legend'?" sounds unnatural, but it can be improved greatly with the addition of a couple of words: "What is the meaning of the word 'legend'?"

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I discarded that idea as it's even longer, and I prefer brevity over verbosity. At the end of the day, "what does X mean?" is usually the best form anyway.

Comment: @Spiritman I think that the longer version is more common because there can be some ambiguity in speech. For example: "What does Daisy mean?" vs. "What does 'daisy' mean?"